# Find its length. Is the length finite? Find the arclength parametrization of $\varphi .$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

> - Consider the "infinite spiral" $\varphi(t)=\left(e^{-t} \cos t, e^{-t} \sin t\right), t \in[0, \infty) .$ Find its length. Is the length finite? Find the arclength parametrization of $\varphi .$

My attempt: I used arc length formula: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \sqrt{\left(-e^{-t} \cos (t)-e^{-t} \sin (t)\right)^{2}+\left(-e^{-t} \sin (t)+e^{-t} \cos (t)\right)^{2}} d t=\sqrt{2}$

1) How can I say that is the length finite?

2) How can I find the arclength parametrization of $\varphi$? Can you help?

Comment: 1) How can I say that is the length finite? $\to$ same way how you find $\sqrt{2}$.

2) How can I find the arclength parametrization of φ? $\to$ same way how you write the integral.

Comment: that was a typo, sorry

Comment: @CanTurkun Thanks for helping but I couldn't understand :(. How same way???

Comment: @CanTurkun Can you add an aswer?

Comment: 1. you already answered it. Is $\sqrt 2$ finite

Comment: @user26977 okeyy, ıt is finite :)

Comment: @user26977 can you help for $2)$?

Comment: @JamesEnsor For second part. Start with $s(t) = \int_{0}^t} \sqrt{\left(-e^{-t} \cos (t)-e^{-t} \sin (t)\right)^{2}+\left(-e^{-t} \sin (t)+e^{-t} \cos (t)\right)^{2}} d t$, Solve for $t$ in terms of s and put it back in parameterization you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find arclength parametrization:

Let $\displaystyle s = \int_0^t \sqrt{[(e^{-u}\cos u)']^2 + [(e^{-u}\sin u)']^2} \, du$

$\displaystyle = \int_{0}^{t} \sqrt{\left(-e^{-u} \cos(u) - e^{-u} \sin(u)\right)^{2} + \left(-e^{-u} \sin(u)+e^{-u} \cos(u)\right)^{2}} \, du$

$\displaystyle = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-u} \sqrt{(\cos(u)+\sin(u))^2+(\cos(u) - \sin(u))^2} \, du  $

$\displaystyle = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-u} \sqrt{2 \cos^2 u + 2 \sin^2 u} \, du = \sqrt{2} \int_{0}^{t} e^{-u} = \sqrt{2}(1-e^{-t})$

(Here $s \to \sqrt{2}$, a finite number, as $t \to \infty$ means the length is finite.)

So, $s = \sqrt{2}(1-e^{-t}) \implies e^{-t} = 1 - \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}} \implies t = -\ln \left( 1 - \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}} \right) = \ln \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} - s} \right)$.

Hence the arclength parametrization is putting this $t$ in the original $\varphi(t) = (e^{-t} \cos(t), e^{-t} \sin(t))$:

$\left( \left( 1 - \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\cos \left( \ln \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} - s} \right) \right) , \left( 1 - \dfrac{s}{\sqrt{2}} \right)\sin \left( \ln \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2} - s} \right) \right) \right)$

Comment: Thanks for answer :) And welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: You are welcome :) Yes I am new here, thanks for the warm welcoming with this question :)

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates  $ r=e^{-t}$

$$s= \varphi(t)=\int _{t}  ^{\infty} \sqrt{ r^2+r^{'2}\,} dt  $$

$$=\sqrt2 \, (e^{-t}-1)$$
which tends to a finite limit as $t \rightarrow \infty.$